# Convert specific CSS elements to jQuery for transforms

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll, transform

I've been trying to figure out how to convert this CSS into jQuery for a few days now without success.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to get some scrolling going on several articles.

Currently I'm giving each article a separate panel id, like panel1, panel2 etc and they slide with different values, from -100vh to -500vh etc. Problem is, that isn't very optimised and I can foresee having 100s of sections in the future.

The CSS for the first panels are as follows:

```
a[ id= "anchor2" ]:target ~ #main article.panels {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -100vh);
}

a[ id= "anchor3" ]:target ~ #main article.panels {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -200vh);
}

a[ id= "anchor4" ]:target ~ #main article.panels {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -300vh);
}

a[ id= "anchor5" ]:target ~ #main article.panels {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -400vh);
}
```

But I'd like to put it in jQuery so I can automate the scrolling and just put the panel id in a variable and automate it, rather than fill up the CSS with a ton of unique inputs.

If I could put something like this in a jQuery, I think I would be the right way:

```
a[ id= "anchor5" ]:target ~ #main article.panels {-webkit-transform: translateY( -' + currentHeight + 'vh);}
```

I'm still a big green around the edges of HTML5, CSS and jQuery, but I've been slowly learning by reading the posts and questions on here, but this is something i haven't been able to clue out yet. So if anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: What's the relevant HTML for this part of your site? And, incidentally, I'd second the call to read the [ask] guidelines, and also the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You mean automatic scrolling? Sounds like a jQuery carousel would be a good option. [This one](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is the one I use most, and I recommend it. See the examples and you'll see that it's fairly simple to use and should work for you.